# What is the difference between mixin module and mixin::with module in perl?

Tags: perl, mixing

I don't know what's the difference between the `mixin` and `mixin::with` module?

```
package Dog;
sub speak { print "Bark!\n" }
sub new { my $class = shift;  bless {}, $class }

package Dog::Small;
use base 'Dog';
sub speak { print "Yip!\n"; }

package Dog::Retriever;
use mixin::with 'Dog';
sub fetch { print "Get your own stinking $_[1]\n" }

package Dog::Small::Retriever;
use base 'Dog::Small';
use mixin 'Dog::Retriever';

my $small_retriever = Dog::Small::Retriever->new;
$small_retriever->speak;          # Yip!
$small_retriever->fetch('ball');  # Get your own stinking ball
```

In the code above, can the following code :

```
package Dog::Small::Retriever;
use base 'Dog::Small';
use mixin 'Dog::Retriever';
```

be replaced with the following one?

```
package Dog::Small::Retriever;
#use base 'Dog::Small';
use mixin:with 'Dog::Retriever';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though mixin::with is intended for use in defining classes which add/change behaviors (Dog::Small and Dog::Retriever in your example), while mixin is used in the final consuming class (Dog::Small::Retriever).

But also note that the [documentation for mixin::with](https://metacpan.org/module/mixin%3a%3awith) suggests "Instead of mixins, please consider using traits. See Class::Trait for an implementation." Class::Trait, in turn, is deprecated and suggests Moose::Role.

Oh - you cannot skip the `use base 'Dog::Small'` declaration - if you did, your class would not inherit from `Dog::Small` (or `Dog`).

Comment: Dog::Retriver inherit the Dog::Small; so i need not use base 'Dog::Small' ??

Comment: No, `Dog::Retriever` inherits nothing on its own.  The `use mixin::with 'Dog'` statement declares that Dog::Retriever can be called as a mixin by a class which inherits `Dog`.

Comment: i call `speak` on `Dog::Retriver` is ok, but call `speak` on `Dog::Small::Retriver` is failed when no inherit `Dog`; i don't know the author why must let me inherit `Dog` when use the `mixin`ed class.

Comment: Just to emphasize my second paragraph - this module has been basically replaced by `Moose::Role` - if you are writing new code, you should start there instead of `mixin` and `mixin::with`.